# How can I select elements inside @Html.BeginForm with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC C# application, and I'm trying to code a simple click event that triggers when the submit button in a form is clicked.

The issue is that the $('.class') selector is seemingly blind to everything inside my @Html.BeginForm(yada yada yada) {} clause.

An alert in $(document).ready() will fire so I know that jQuery is loaded and working, but an alert in $('.myButton').click() will not fire.

Here is my .cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageProducts", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "productForm" }))
{
...
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="add btn btn-default" />
}
```

Here is my jQuery

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.add').click(function (e) {
            alert('Hi');
            $('input:text').val('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

Things I have tried:

- put a button outside the form, alert fired
- $('#productForm .add').click(...), alert still doesn't fire
- $('input:button').click(...), alert still doesn't fire
- $('#productForm').find('.add').click(...), alert still doesn't fire
- Googled for about two hours, alert still doesn't fire :(

Sorry if this seems to be a duplicate, but even though I have actually found several posts with this same question, the "correct" answer is always either the 2nd or 4th item in the above list, and yet those do not fix my issue.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The code you have shown works fine and clicking on your submit button will alert "Hi". If its not working for you, then its because of code you have not shown us.

Comment: I mean, it's basically a brand new MVC project. There is no additional code to show...

Answer (score 0):

As it is right now the form will try to submit to the ManageProducts action of your Admin controller when that input is clicked instead if firing jquery.  One option for you would be to fire your logic on submit instead of that controller action.  Something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { onsubmit = "return alertStuff();" }))

<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertStuff() {
        alert('Hi');
    }
</script>
```

I have also had luck using the on submit function of jquery.  Something like this has worked for me before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#productForm").on("submit", function () {
            alert('Hi');
            if (youDontWantToSubmitForm) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```